# print() doesn't work on Firefox

Tags: firefox, printing

I've made a code for printing some image from my website .
the body just like this

```
<body>
  <img src="http://localhost/upload/qrsample.png" id="barcode">
  <a>
  <img src="http://localhost/upload/icon_printer.png" onclick="javascript:printImg()">
  </a>
</body>
```

and the javascript function like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function printImg() {
    pwin = window.open(document.getElementById("barcode").src);
    pwin.print();
  }
</script>
```

it works fine on Chrome, but it doesn't work on Firefox . but my website should run on Firefox, so can anyone help me to solve this problem ?
should I change the browser or the code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public standard that applies to the Window object, but all major browsers mostly support it.

```
function printImg() {

ImageLink=document.getElementById("barcode").src;
pwin=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
pwin.document.write("<img src='" + ImageLink + "'/>");
pwin.print();

}
```

I think this will solve the problem. or may be you could have set pop-up blocker, because this creates a new window this could have failed,

Comment: thankyou for your answer . it works and it helps me a lot :)
but , could you tell me how to add time to the open window ? I want it appear just 2 second .